# Como habilitar la transición de SplitView

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

Estoy creando una aplicación universal con un HamburgerMenu

```
<Grid>
    <SplitView x:Name="hMenu" IsPaneOpen="{Binding ElementName=hMenuBtn, Path=IsChecked}">
        <SplitView.Pane>
            <RelativePanel>

            </RelativePanel>
        </SplitView.Pane>  
    </SplitView>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="48" 
                VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                Background="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundAccentBrush}">
        <ToggleButton x:Name="hMenuBtn" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="48"
                      HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
        </ToggleButton>
        <TextBlock Foreground="White" Text="Control De Materiales"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                   FontSize="20" Margin="10 20 0 0"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Funciona correctamente, pero al pulsar el `ToogleButton` el `Pane` se abre brúscamente sin mostrar ninguna transición.

He tratado de agregarla mediante `TransitionCollection`, pero no consigo que funcione.

Comment: Cómo te fue con esto?

Comment: Hola @JuanK, Me sirvió mucho tu respuesta pero desde que actualice Visual Studio a la Update 1 la transición se implementa sola. Gracias

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se debe hacer así:

```
<SplitView x:Name="hMenu" IsPaneOpen="{Binding ElementName=hMenuBtn, Path=IsChecked}">
    <TransitionCollection>
        <ExponentialEase />
    </TransitionCollection>
    <SplitView.Pane>
        <RelativePanel>

        </RelativePanel>
    </SplitView.Pane>  
</SplitView>
```

desde luego tambien lo puedes probar desde C# y debería funcionar sin lio.

```
hMenu.ChildrenTransitions = new 
             TransitionCollection {new ExponentialEase ()};
```

Sin embargo recuerda que las apps están preparadas par dispositivos de low end, por ende esto gasta mucha energía y procesamiento que puede que no tengas. Así que si estás haciendo animaciones personalizadas debes intencionalmente decir que ejecutaras animaciones en objetos dependientes, y esto se hace de esta manera: `EnableDependentAnimation="true"` en el objeto de animación que estés utlizando:

```
<PointAnimation EnableDependentAnimation="true" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Buenas, yo uso la plantilla `navpanel`, para generar automáticamente proyectos con `splitview` (menú lateral deslizante), la misma plantilla incluye los efectos del menú y transición entre views.

[Nav Pane App Template (Universal Windows)](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/7284fa56-cd50-4d66-ba61-03ee77bddd19)